# Show a timer in a Java Frame

Tags: java, time

I want to show the elapsed time of a game i'm doing. Basically i want to call the class that keeps track of the score and with calling the class i want to start a timer that just continually runs and shows the elapsed time, this should be added.

Is there any way to do this without using System.Currenttime, i tried using that but it seems like there should be an easier way, since I don't really need a lot of precision, I just want it to start counting and close with the rest of the program.

Comment: The event object has a method `getWhen()`. It may help you.

Comment: You can use the StopWatch class from Apache Commons. Link: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to create a timer:

```
timer = new Timer(speed, this);
timer.setInitialDelay(pause);
timer.start();
```

I would put 1000 in speed so that it updates every 1 second, (since the times goes my milliseconds.)

Next, I would create a label in your java program:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Text Here");
add(label);
```

Then, I would do this:

```
label.setText(timer.toString());
```

That is basically how you add a timer to a label on a JFrame.  For more advanced methods, these websites might help:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

http://www.javabeginner.com/java-jlabel-class-example/

[How do you change label text in java after a timer ticks a second passed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523841/how-do-you-change-label-text-in-java-after-a-timer-ticks-a-second-passed)

Please +1 this answer if it helped you! :)

Comment: That would be helpful.  I was just giving the abridged version of how to do it.

Comment: @OSryx, he doesn't need a separate thread. The Timer will invoke an event every second. So you just need to track the time when the Timer was started and then the current timer. The difference will give you the elapsed time. (+1)

Comment: so if i am understanding that right, i need to record the starting time, and then in the action listener i need to subtract the starting time from the current time and show the result. Because right now the label shows this:    javax.swing.JLabel[,163,208,171x16,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=javax.swing.Timer@3adb3271,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]

Comment: Pretty much. Remember, you have to calculate the difference and add .toString() afterwards.